# Creating a virtualenv for Python 3.8.0 returns a Path does not exist error

Tags: ubuntu, virtualenv, python-3.8

I am very new to Ubuntu and am trying to create a `virtualenv` for Python 3.8.0.

- Python 3.8.0 is installed in `C:/usr/local/opt/python-3.8.0/bin`.
- I am using the following command to create the virtualenv:

  virtualenv slm -python='C:/usr/local/opt/python-3.8.0/bin'
- The following error is returned:

  The path ython=C:/usr/local/opt/python-3.8.0/bin (from --python=ython=C:/usr/local/opt/python-3.8.0/bin) does not exist.
- The folder does exist - the path was copied from the File Manager.

I am guessing from the "ython=" (the loss of the 'p' in "python") that the command is running afoul of the python environment variable.

However, if I `unset python` and repeat the `virtualenv` command above, I get the same error.

A large part of this is my complete unfamiliarity with Ubuntu.  Could someone comment on what is going on with the `virtualenv` command?

Comment: `-p C:/usr/local/opt/python-3.8.0/bin/python` or `--python=C:/usr/local/opt/python-3.8.0/bin/python` (double dashes, currently you show a single dash in the command). And `/python` at the tail — it must point to an executable, not to a directory.

Comment: The solution is virtualenv slm --python='/usr/local/opt/python-3.8.0/bin/python3.8'.  Note that if C: is included in the path, the error: path does not exist is thrown.

Comment: phd - could you post your note as an answer?  I will mark it as the  solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option for `virtualenv` is [either `-p` (single dash, short option) or `--python=` (double dashes, long option)](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/cli_interface.html#section-discovery). That is either

```
virtualenv -p C:/usr/local/opt/python-3.8.0/bin/python
```

or

```
virtualenv --python=C:/usr/local/opt/python-3.8.0/bin/python
```

Note `/python` at the tail — it must point to an executable, not to a directory.